# Guiding tables below the maps and color-coded tables in English

Tags: american-english, british-english, translation, science, geography

Usually, there is a guiding table below the maps and color-coded tables, to help reader what is the meaning of each color or element. What is that table called in English?

Comment: @jejorda2 perfect, thank you. It is called legend

Comment: A synonym for 'legend' is 'key', since this table 'unlocks' the meaning of the symbols.